# Update Fields - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to update null fields in a table with existing vales in the table.

Example:

Table has 4 columns:A,B,C,D

```
A     B     C     D
1     2     3     4
5     Null  Null  4
```

How can I populate the Null values with the values in B,C where D=4

```
Update Table
Set B=B
Where B is null
and D=4
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question: What are you updating the nulls to? B and C are null. do you want them copied from row A1 into A5? For that we may need more context. You can do a lag and based on order and populate it like that, but that will break if you have 2 nulls in consequtive rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `self join`:

```
update t
set t.b = t2.b
from yourtable t
    join yourtable t2 on t.d = t2.d 
                    and t2.b is not null
where t.b is null
```

---

What if multiple records exist for b grouped by d where b is not null?  That could mess this up.  Instead you'd have to decide which value to use.  Here's an example choosing the `min`:

```
update t
set t.b = t2.b
from yourtable t
    join (select d, min(b) b 
          from yourtable
          where b is not null
          group by d) t2 on t.d = t2.d 
where t.b is null
```

---

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
update yourtable t
set b = (select min(b) from yourtable t2 where t.id = t2.id)
where t.b is null
```

A lot of options here...

Comment: i want to update the null fields where d is the same.  If D=4 for 3 records, the values in b and c may be different, but I want them to appear in any row where in columns b and c where D=4.

Comment: @Jeff -- all of these queries do just that... What if `d` is the same but has multiple `b` values that aren't `null`?  Which value do you use?  That's what this answer tries to address for you.  Depends on what you're trying to do.  These options should be close though.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are only single values in B & C.  Any values where D=D, I want to copy the values over to B & C that are null.